# Multiple Child Selector CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

If I have the following code :

```
<ul>
    <li>Unordered item</li>
    <li>Unordered item
        <ol>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How can I access **Item 2** using **:nth-child** selector without using **:last-child**?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access like this

```
ol li:nth-child(2)
```

or

```
ul ol li:nth-child(2)
```

Comment: Related JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/katheer_mizal/ws3L6a71/2/

Answer (score 0):

Using `nth-child(2)`

```css
ol li:nth-child(2){
color:red;}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Unordered item</li>
    <li>Unordered item
        <ol>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ul>
```